# UITableViewCell text color gets changed on selection of row, why?

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, ios4

I have used UITableView with default UITableViewCell.

Here i have given dark gray color in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, also set one imageView to selectedBackgroundView.

So now when i select that row, particular selected image is getting displayed, but my textColor gets changed to White from Dark Gray.

Why so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UILabel` is getting highlighted together with it's master view. Change it's `highlightedTextColor`, the default is white for you. For example

```
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```